# Mapping values to different sets of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, mapping, radio-button

I have a difficult case of mapping value arrays to different radio buttons. Here is the HTML, I've renamed the variables to make it generic and not specific to the particular web form I'm making now.

```
<input type="radio" NAME="type" id="rbtA"><span id="txtA">Alt. A</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="type" id="rbtB"><span id="txtB">Alt. B</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="type" id="rbtC"><span id="txtC">Alt. C</span>

<input type="radio" NAME="COM" id="rbtSub1"><span id="txtSub1">SubAlt. 1</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="COM" id="rbtSub2"><span id="txtSub2">SubAlt. 2</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="COM" id="rbtSub3"><span id="txtSub3">SubAlt. 3</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="COM" id="rbtSub4"><span id="txtSub4">SubAlt. 4</span>

<input type="radio" NAME="Coupling" id="rbtSubSub1"><span id="txtSubSub1">Yes</span>
<input type="radio" NAME="Coupling" id="rbtSubSub2"><span id="txtSubSub2">No</span>

<SELECT id="selectCom" style="width: 160" NAME="Communication"><OPTION selected="selected"></OPTION></SELECT>
```

If alternative B or C is selected, radio buttons rbtSub1-rbtSub4 will appear. If C is selected, rbtSubSub1 and rbtSubSub2 will stay hidden, but if B *and* (SubAlt. 1 or SubAlt. 2) are selected, rbtSubSub1 and rbtSubSub2 will appear. To make these buttons appear/disappear is no problem, the problem is to map the correct alternatives to the selectbox selectCom depending on which radio buttons are selected.

If the alternatives in selectCom only depended on rbtSub1 - rbtSub4, the mapping would be easy:

```
var arraySub1=["1A", "1B", "1C"];
//(correspondingly for sub2 and sub3)...
var arraySub4=["4A", "4B", "4C"];
var mapCom = { rbtSub1 : arraySub1, rbtSub2 : arraySub2, rbtSub3 : arraySub3, rbtSub4 : arraySub4 }
```

Then somewhere in the jquery code I would have this code to populate selectCom depending on which sub alternative the user selects (this works, I've used this other places in the form):

```
$('#rbtSub1, #rbtSub2, #rbtSub3, #rbtSub4').change(function() {
  $("#selectCom option").remove();
  $.each(mapCom[this.id], function(i, val) {
    var opt = $("<option />");
    opt.appendTo($("#selectCom")).text(val).val(val);
  });
});
```

The tricky part is that if rbtB *and* (rbtSub1 or rbtSub2) are selected, I need to populate selectCom depending on whether the user selects rbtSubSub1 or rbtSubSub2, but if rbt B and (rbtSub3 or rbtSub4) are selected, I need to populate selectCom depending on whether the user has selected rbtSub3 or rbtSub4. Furthermore, if rbtC was selected, I only want to populate selectCom depending on which was selected: rbtSub1, rbtSub2, rbtSub3 or rbtSub4.

I have tried mapping radio buttons that are not on the same level in the same mapping code line, but this causes an error when I try to run the form.

Any good suggestions to how I can achieve this?

Comment: After a good nights sleep and some more troubleshooting I think I have found, if not a solution to my original problem, at least a valid workaround. It's not elegant, but it works.

I create a triple set of buttons, one that's visible if rbtA's selected, one if rbtB's selected etc. For the user, the buttons look the same. Then I create three mappings and three functions to populate selectCom, each function corresponding to one of the three sets of buttons. I haven't yet implemented it fully, I might have to create a fourth function for the subsub buttons.

Cumbersome, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be in php... breaking up the html, putting an IF statement in there if value X or X is selected the echo style="display:none"

Comment: The problem is that my company is part of an international concern, and our local office can't upload php files to our local server. I really can't see any good reason for this rule, but that's the way it is.